# Why can't my PCL use System.Runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, portable-class-library, .net-core

I have a PCL that targets the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1

I need to add a reference to [`System.Runtime`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime) because I want to use another package that depends on it. From what I can see, [version 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/4.0.0) appears to include the target platforms mentioned above. However, when I try installing it via NuGet, I get this stack trace:

```
PM> Install-Package System.Runtime -Version 4.0.0
# ...
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'System.Runtime 4.0.0' does not exist in project 'PclDummy'
Package 'System.Runtime 4.0.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PclDummy\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.Runtime 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Why does this happen if `System.Runtime` supports all of the platforms my PCL does?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile with Net 4.5 and the dll was compiled with Net 4.0.  Try changing in the Project Properties the target from Net 4.5 to Net 4.0.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean? [System.Runtime 4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/4.0.0) says that it supports .NET 4.5.

Comment: What you said is backwards.  Visual Studio 2012 and newer comes with Net 4.5 and defaults to Net 4.5,  To work with older versions of of Net you must specifically select and older target.  I would think the runtime with Net 4.5 would be 4.5.0 (not 4.0.0).

Comment: @jdweng 4.0.0 is the version of the library in the package, not the .NET runtime version - as this a new, out of band release, it would effectively replace the System.Runtime library that comes in .Net 4.0 or 4.5  Jame's comment above is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

> that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111'

Be sure to distinguish between *reference* assemblies and *runtime* assemblies.  To get your PCL project compiled, you only need reference assemblies.  And you already have one for System.Runtime, it is located in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile111 directory on your machine.  It is already referenced in your project so the package was correctly rejected.

These kind of crazy "but everybody already has this" Nuget packages come from the CoreCLR project.  It is evolving rapidly right now with beta versions released at a very high rate.  Which is one of the targets supported by Profile111, it supports an ASP.NET Core 5.0 target.  Not one you listed in your question so you probably don't need it at all.  But if you would then it would be *that* project that downloads this Nuget package.  Which is entirely automatic, you don't ask for the packages explicitly.

Just stop trying to get it installed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I'm asking because I have an ASP.NET 5 + project.json-based NuGet package that I'd like to use in the PCL, but it seems to be failing because of its dependency on System.Runtime. If not `System.Runtime` itself, is there anything I can do to get that package installed?

Comment: Well, nice job documenting that in your question.  "Seems to be failing", what on Earth does that mean?  Click the Ask Question button and document your issue properly.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that System.Runtime is not completely supported in version 4.5.

you can check it in the profile folder in following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile111
```

there is a list of supported assemblies and namespaces.