# Why isn't this .NET Core package compatible with my PCL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, asp.net-core

I have a PCL that targets the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1

I also have another package (called **Enu**), based off .NET Core and `project.json`, that I would like to use in this PCL. My problem is, when I try to install the .NET Core package into my PCL, I receive an error message saying that the PCL isn't compatible with the package.

```
PM> Install-Package Enu
# lots of output...
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Enu 4.4.0' does not exist in project 'PclDummy'
Package 'Enu 4.4.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PclDummy\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Enu 4.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

After digging into the issue for a bit, I found out that a package Enu depends on, specifically `System.Runtime (v4.0.0)`, appeared to be having issues as well ([related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803961/why-cant-my-pcl-use-system-runtime)) installing on my PCL. The strange thing is, while it claims to be incompatible with my library, it [supports all of the target platforms I do](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/4.0.0), so I don't see why this is the case.

---

**TL;DR:** NuGet won't allow a .NET Core package to be installed on PCL because it thinks they're incompatible. After investigating, I found out the root of the problem was a dependency of the package was incompatible with the PCL, even though [it supports all of the platforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/4.0.0) my PCL does. Why is this happening?

Here's the [project.json](https://github.com/jamesqo/enu/blob/master/src/Enu/project.json) file for the .NET Core package, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Claies Whoops, accidentally linked to the `project.json` on my master branch. [**Here**](https://github.com/jamesqo/enu/blob/5b4cc4668dcf8791d8dd004dabd42fa4657a3654/src/Enu/project.json) was how it looked like at the time of writing.

Comment: I was a bit quick on my comment anyway; I'm still researching the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so after three weeks of banging my head on this, I have finally (**FINALLY**) solved the problem. Here is my new, working `project.json`:

```
{
    ...

    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20"
            }
        },
        ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Runtime": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to Mark for giving me the idea and whoever [these guys](https://github.com/search?l=json&q=.NETPortable&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) are.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying is not supported, because you're creating a PCL which allows only the common subset of .NET 4.5, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 and you're trying to add a reference to this PCL which is a superset of the API you're allowing. This would create a conflict, because the Enu package might use APIs that are not available on .NET 4.5, Windows 8 and/or Windows Phone 8.1.

To use a .NET Core library, you must create a .NET 4.5 library or use a replacement of the **Enu** library which is itself a PCL which uses the same  (.NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1)or a smaller subset of the .NET API (.NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1 and e.g. Windows Phone 8 Silverlight).

EDIT: A look at your NuGet package reveals, that you have a library which targets .NET 4.5, Windows 8, and Windows Phone 8.1, but you have different assemblies for all platforms, but what you'd need to use it in a PCL is a single assembly which can be used across all platforms. The NuGet platform identifier would be "portable-net45+win+wpa81".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, found it really helpful! One thing though: since **Enu** targets said platforms (`net45+win+wpa81`), how can it possibly use APIs not available in those platforms? Wouldn't it be a subset of the APIs consumed by the PCL?

Comment: .NET Core is a subset of .NET 4.5, but is still a superset of Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1. Therefore, when you write a PCL which uses only a common subset of .NET 4.5, Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1, you're using a subset of .NET Core 5. This also means that .NET Core 5 contains APIs not available for Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8.1.
.NET Core contains ```System.Security.Cryptography```, but .NET for Windows 8.1 doesn't. There are other Namespaces which aren't available, but this should give you some hints.

Comment: *Finally* got it working after trying the suggestion in your edit, thank you so much! I'll award you the bounty when it lets me in 9 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Targeting `dotnet` in your project.json will not include Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.1. Try adding `netcore45` and `wpa81` in your target frameworks.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! You seem to be one of the few people here knowledgeable about .NET Core. I tried your suggestion and added the TFMs for Windows 8 + Windows Phone 8.1 ([new project.json](https://github.com/jamesqo/enu/blob/master/src/Enu/project.json)), but I'm getting the same errors. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm working on a new project based off ASP.NET 5 so I need to do a lot of reading/digging about it (incl .NET Core). Not really as knowledgeable as those who are in the team but I'm happy to help and share what I've known so far. Anyway, how are you referencing the **Enu** package in your PCL? Do you have a private nuget repo?

Comment: Not really; I upload it to nuget.org and then do `Install-Package Enu` from my PCL.